# When plotting implicit xy equations, it gives me broken graphs.

Tags: calculus, random-graphs

So I'm trying to make my own implicit equation and plot it using desmos.com (cant link because of rep)

Everything is fine, I'm using this method:

$( y - f(x) ) ( y - g(x) ) .... = 0$

For example, if I plot

$(y-x^2)(y-x)=0$

it plots fine (both curevs).

However, if I add this 'factor': $(y+\sqrt{1-(x-2)^2}-2)$ everything get 'restricted' in a weird way. See this image:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/woVjq.png (all three factors)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/YgxKh.png (without the troubling factor)

Why is this happening? How can I fix it?

Comment: The third function has a domain where $(x-2)^2\leq 1$, which means $1\leq x\leq 3$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The third factor only takes values between $1 \geq x \geq 3$. Therefore, the entire function's domain is restricted to that area. This is because:

$\sqrt{1-(x-2)^2}$ means that $1-(x-2)^2 \geq 0$, leading to $1 \geq (x-2)^2$

Take the square root of both sides to get:

$$1 \geq \left| (x-2) \right|$$
$$-1 \leq x-2 \leq 1$$

So $x$ can only be in the domain:

$$1 \leq x \leq 3$$

If there isn't any reason why not, I suggest that you enter the factors separately and set them all to 0, as this will yield the same graph, and according to my tests, does work.

If you are unclear about why they would yield the same graph, it is because, for your equation to equal zero, one of the factors must equal zero and, conversely, if one of your factors equals zero, then your entire equation does as well.

Therefore, you would enter your equations as such:

$$(y-x^2)=0$$
$$(y-x)=0$$
$$(y-\sqrt{1-(x-2)^2}-2 = 0$$

Comment: Thanks. I am actually trying to merge the three equations (not these three, but a bunch more, I only gave these as an example). I know that they work when separated but isn't there any way to keep them together and get satisfactory results?

All I need it an equation of a semi circle that isn't restricted like the one I already have.

Comment: Actually, finding the equation of a circle that is not restricted will be impossible, because the idea of a circle is that the equation becomes invalid beyond certain x and y values. However, try this: 

$$\sqrt{1-(x-2)^2}=2-y$$
$$1-(x-2)^2=(2-y)^2$$

That makes it a full circle if that's what you want, but further than that, the equation of a circle makes it impossible to evaluate in the real plane outside of that small area. Therefore, either accept you need complex numbers or split up the equations

Comment: Here, let me explain:

The equation of a circle is given by this: $r^2 = x^2 + y^2$

A semicircle by: $y=\sqrt{r^2-x^2}$

For the first example, solving for y gives $\left| y \right| = \sqrt{r^2-x^2}$. This means that $\left| x \right|$ must be smaller than $\left| r \right|$. This still holds equally true for the equation defining a semicircle. There is no way to get around this, as a circle is, by definition, finite, and therefore its equation must be restricted as well. All shapes defined by equations have this characteristic.